# How to related specific array key value for each item in PHP?

Tags: php

Now I'm creating a cart system using PHP which functions as following:
When I press the "Add to cart" button it sends the id, quantity selected and the size of the specific product to the session storage

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ('databaseConnection.php');
include_once ('productPage.php');

if (isset($_POST['addTocart'])) {
    $url = $_POST["urlHidden"];
    $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
    $size = $_POST["size"];
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], "product_id");
        if (in_array($_POST['productIdHidden'], $item_array_id)) {
            header("Location: $url?status=alreadyadded");
            exit();
        } else {
            $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $item_array = array('product_id' => $_POST['productIdHidden'], 'quantity' => $quantity, 'size' => $size);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$count] = $item_array;
            header("Location: $url?status=addedtocart");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

then in the cart I select all the products from the database and only allow the products with id matching the ids stored in the session storage. the following code is what is happening inside the cart.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
$product_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     foreach ($product_id as $id) {
            if ($row['product_id'] == $id) {
                cartElement($row['product_id'], $row['product_image'], $row['product_name'], $row['product_price']);
                $productPrice = (int)$row['product_price'];
                $total = $total + $productPrice;
            }
        }
    }
    
} else {
  echo "<h1>Your cart is empty</h1>";
}
```

Now I have the product id, selected quantity and size stored in the session array "I added them using the "add to cart" button"

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( [productid] => 1403 [quantity] => 4 [size] => s )
 [1] => Array ( [productid] => 1302 [quantity] => 2 [size] => m )
 [2] => Array ( [productid] => 1202 [quantity] => 3 [size] => l )
)
```

, my goal is while it is checking for the product id in the session array it also check for the quantity and the size and then relate each of them to each product so each displayed in the cart will have it's own quantity and size so I can update the cart total to be like this
"$total = $total + ($quantity * $productPrice);"

Comment: I don't understand the issue. _"...so every single products in the cart will have it's own quantity and size."_ sounds like the exact thing you have right now. Can you clarify what it is you want to be different? Maybe an example would help.

Comment: ok I edited the last section hope it is clearer right now.

Comment: Hello. Can you share the content of $_SESSION['cart']? What does function 'cartElement()' do? Can you confirm that if the same product is added twice to the cart, there will be only one line for that product but with the sum of quantities? If the previous is true, then it is a matter of how you store your cart lines in the session. You must store them in a way that allows you to quickly retrieve a line for a given product_id; for example use the product_id as key for each cart line entry; but again you must make sure that you don't store duplicates in your cart for the same product_id.

Answer (score 0):

**[OFF]**

You can simplify your code if extend SQL query with product IDs which are in the cart:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');

    $id_sql_array = array_map(function($val) { return "'" . $val . "'"; }, $product_ids);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN ". '(' . implode(',', $id_sql_array) .");";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        cartElement($row['product_id'], $row['product_image'], $row['product_name'], $row['product_price']);
        $productPrice = (int)$row['product_price'];
        $total = $total + $productPrice;
    }
    
} else {
  echo "<h1>Your cart is empty</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but that is not my issue, what I want is to send the quantity and the size selected by the user to the cart so I can update the cart total

Comment: "but that is not my issue" It will be later! If you have a lot of products, your website will be slow because you are currently querying all the data for all the products.

But your attach code snippet is not fully related to solving the problem. Please add the "add to cart" function to the question too.

Comment: Ok I got it thanks, And I added the "add to cart" function code